# Creating Chat application in Website

Tags: c#

I want to create a chat application in my website so that they can chat to each other.
It should also support single user chatting and multiuser chatting .

Please suggest me , that how to start this. Any tutorial link or suggestion is welcomed. I want to create it in .Net framework in c#

Comment: you might want to check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224874/c-server-client-applications/5224923#5224923

Comment: My advice would be to get a beginner's book on ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC. You can't properly learn this by reading blogs and newsgroups only. At least not in a decent amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this site and steal, steal, steal:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I am looking to include a chat application in my asp.net mvc website: Could you please give more details about this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) and [Jabbr.net](http://jabbr.net).